# assigning .overrideColor values to buttons in Maya

Tags: python, button, rgb, maya, curves

I want to assign all 31 colors from the .overrideColors attribute to 31 generated buttons in Maya via Python. The bgc option from cmds.button only allows me to put 3 float values. How can I create those colors ? It is supposed to change the color of a curve by clicking the colored button in the UI.

I started with :

```
def UI():
    cmds.window()
    cmds.flowLayout()

    for i in range (0,32)
    cmds.button('')
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to use overrideColorRGB you can always get the overrideColors like this:

```
for i in range(1, 32):
    print cmds.colorIndex(i, q=True)
```

> Output:
>
> [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>
> [0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
>
> [0.6000000238418579, 0.6000000238418579, 0.6000000238418579]
>
> [0.6079999804496765, 0.0, 0.15700000524520874]
>
> ...
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Maya 2016 or later you might find it easier to go the other way. Those colors aren't hard-coded, they are user controlled preference settings (under *Windows > Settings/Preferences > Color Settings* in the active  and inactive tabs) .

In 2016 you can set the wireframe color of an object to an RGB value directly instead of using the old index values.

```
cmds.setAttr("object.overrideColorRGB", 1, 0, 0)
```

for example sets the wireframe to red.